# How can I truly understand mathematics?

Tags: self-learning, education

I don't want to study math without true understanding, Conceptual knowledge is not understanding. Books describe things in an abstract manner without any context. And even worse, they always make assumptions that turns the material inaccessible.

I'm not after procedural knowledge. Is there a method to truly make sense of "mathematical expressions", understand the parts of models and the relationship between them?

P.S: My question may seem vague, but really I want to know how can I truly understand math, not learn a set of actions to solve a problem that I can't contextualize and that I don't know it's why.
If my question still vague please just tell me as a mathematician how you get your aha moments and what you can say to a complete beginner?

Comment: According to John von Neumann, "In mathematics you don't understand things. You just get used to them."

Comment: I would say the way to understand is doing problems in books, but it seems you object to that.

Comment: you need a bit of history of the creation and development of mathematics, that is, context to understand mathematics deeply (or any other thing, not just mathematics). The things that are used all the time in mathematics have a reason to exists, however this information is generally not put in any textbook of mathematics, so you need to dig for yourself or search for the origin of something. You must ask for something specific, your question is too broad. By the other hand I disagree strongly with the quote posted by @Shawn

Comment: @Shaun Well, He has a point, but I don't think that's the case really. People who developed a "mathematical intuition" have grasped the core of principales. They can model real world problems and tackle new challenges with confidence.

Comment: @MattSamuel Doing problems and even mastering solving them is just procedural knowledge. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Procedural_knowledge

Comment: I disagree that it is procedural if the problems are good. That's how i learned the majority of what I know, and I have a PhD, which means I have discovered and written about new mathematics. It may not work for you, but that's how I learned.

Comment: @Masacroso You made a very good point studying the history of the development of mathematics might do. Assuming that this information is available. (I am aware that my question is broad but ... you get the idea :))

Comment: "Books describe things in an abstract manner without any context." Find better books!! A good book *will* give you context and motivation for the topic and will set problems that force you to develop a better understanding. You can even ask here for recommendations using the [tag:book-recommendation] tag.

Comment: what @MattSamuel said must be explained in more detail: it is true that doing mathematics procedurally you get at the time an understanding of the thing you are using (many times happen, but for the general case Im not sure), but it get time (years). It is slow but it can work many times. However there are faster paths knowing special view-points that pin down the intuition or (geometric or conceptual) structure behind some abstract thing, but the development of these view-points can take centuries some times, and in many areas of mathematics these view-points are not created yet

Comment: @Rahul the best books have not be written yet, specially books focused to a deeper understanding of mathematics, and by the other hand in many areas of mathematics the are just a few books

Comment: @Masacroso: It sounds like you are talking about research mathematics, while the OP is in their own words "a complete beginner". Also, just because a better book may be written in the future is no reason not to read a good book now.

Comment: @Rahul I didnt said something about "not reading" books